# ostream& and istream& not defined properly

Tags: c++

The compiler is giving me the following error message: "Unkown type name 'ostream' and 'Unknown type name 'istream' 
 And also 'use of undeclared identifier 'ios_base'. Should I add any type of header or? The same error appears in the header file too. I don't know what's wrong because I literally copied the code from the book. (was supposed to)
 Here is my code:

```
#include "chrono.h"
//The definitions go into Chrono.cpp:

// Chrono.cpp

namespace Chrono {

    // member function definitions:

    Date::Date(int yy, Month mm, int dd)
    :y{yy}, m{mm}, d{dd}
    {
        if (!is_date(yy,mm,dd)) throw Invalid{};
    }

    const Date& default_date()
    {
        static Date dd {2001,Month::jan,1};
        return dd;
    }
    Date::Date()
        :y{default_date().year()},
        m{default_date().month()},
        d{default_date().day()}
    {
    }
    void Date:: add_day(int n)
    {
        //..
    }
    void Date::add_month(int n){
        //..
    }
    void Date::add_year(int n){
        if (m==feb && d==29 && !leapyear(y+n)) { // beware of leap years!
            // makes sense for both positive and negative n (n==0 should be impossible here)
            m = mar;        // use March 1 instead of February 29
            d = 1;
        }
        y+=n;
    }
// helper functions

    bool is_date(int y, Month m, int d)
    {
        // assume that y is valid

        if (d<=0) return false;            // d must be positive
        if (m<Month::jan || Month::dec<m) return false;

        int days_in_month = 31;             // most months have 31 days

        switch(m) {
            case Month::feb:
                days_in_month = (leapyear(y))?29:28;
                break;
            case Month::apr: case Month::jun: case Month::sep: case Month::nov:
                days_in_month =30;
                break;
        }
        if (days_in_month<d) return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool leapyear(int y)
    {
        // see exercise 10
    }

    bool operator==(const Date& a, const Date& b)
    {
        return a.year()==b.year()
        && a.month()==b.month()
        && a.day()==b.day();
    }


    bool operator!=(const Date& a, const Date& b)
    {
        return !(a==b);
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d)
    {
        return os << '(' << d.year()
        << ',' << d.month()
        << ',' << d.day()<<')';
    }


    istream& operator>>(istream& is, Date& dd)
    {
        int y, m, d;
        char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
        is >> ch1 >> y >> ch2 >> m >> ch3 >> d >> ch4;
        if (!is) return is;
        if (ch1!='(' || ch2!=',' || ch3!=',' || ch4!=')') { // oops: format error
            is.clear(ios_base::failbit);                    // set the fail bit
            return is;
        }
        dd = Date(y,Month(m),d);     // update dd
        return is;
    }

    enum class Day {
        sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday
    };

    Day day_of_week(const Date& d)
    {
        //..
    }
    Date next_Sunday(const Date& d)
    {
        //..
    }
    Date next_weekday(const Date& d)
    {
        //..
    }

}
```

This is the header file

//chrono.h

```
namespace Chrono {

    enum Month {
        jan=1, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec
    };

    class Date {
    public:

        class Invalid { };                 // to throw as exception

        Date(int y, Month m, int d);       // check for valid date and initialize
        Date();                            // default constructor
        // the default copy operations are fine

        // non-modifying operations:
        int   day()   const { return d; }
        Month month() const { return m; }
        int   year()  const { return y; }

        // modifying operations:
        void add_day(int n);
        void add_month(int n);
        void add_year(int n);
    private:
        int   y;
        Month m;
        int   d;
    };

    bool is_date(int y, Month m, int d); // true for valid date

    bool leapyear(int y);                  // true if y is a leap year

    bool operator==(const Date& a, const Date& b);
    bool operator!=(const Date& a, const Date& b);

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& d);
    istream& operator>>(istream& is, Date& dd);

    Date day_of_week(const Date& d);        // day of week of d
    Date next_Sunday(const Date d);        // next Sunday after d
    Date next_weekday(const date& d);      // next weekday after d
}
```

Comment: `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

In a header you have to add

```
#include <iosfwd>
```

To forward declare iostreams. And use `std::ostream` and `std::istream`

In the cpp - you will use

```
#include <iostream>
```

as suggested by Barmar. And specify namespace std:: as well for members of this namespace.